# How can I retrieve the username and password from my WordPress installation?

Tags: login, password

I had a developer working on a website. Now I learned a bit of WordPress and I would like to continue some of the work on my own. I asked the developer for the passwords and he only gave me the passwords of the hosting account and not from the wp-admin of the WordPress installation. When I asked about those passwords he told me that he never used the wp-admin panel to develop the website and he doesn't know about any passwords about it. He refused to tell me also how he developed the website if not from the panel. Is this even possible? The only way to develop a website is from www.mysite.com/wp-admin, right?

Anyway I still have the passwords from the hosting account that means the ftp passwords and everything. Is the username and password of my website stored in one of the files that are on the ftp account? For example in the wp-config.php file or somewhere else? I can't understand if the developer simply wants more money for it, or I am missing something here.

Comment: if you have access to WordPress database table you can reset password for your account from users table

Comment: About what he said? Is it possible that he doesnt know the passwords of the wp-admin?!??! Can you possibly develop a wordpress site if not from there?

Answer (score 5):

You can reset your/a password in a number of ways. The easiest way is to use a specific [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_FTP).

Or you can do it [through MySQL command line](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_MySQL_Command_Line) or [phpMyAdmin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin), if you have it. Therefore, you have to get your database credentials (if you don't have those already), which you can find in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: I know my databases credentials. Pff seems a bit difficult for me to do that , cause i dont want to break anything on the site , but i ll try. Thanks a lot for your help. Out of curiosity , is the guy lying?? Is it possible that he doesnt know the passwords from wp-admin and he developed the website differently?!

Comment: No, you can **not** develop a WordPress site entirely without the admin. For most things, it _would be_ possible to do so, but most uncomfortable. Who would build a WordPress site using only FTP and SQL? And BTW, using the [`wp_set_password` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) is no magic. ;)

Comment: if you have phpmyadmin you can add a new user which will not break anything just make sure you export the sql first: 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/